# How to prove that $\cos(n)$ is irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers

We know that $\cos(1)$ is real and transcendental **(1)**. Then by using the fact that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a polynomial $P_n$ of degree $n$ with integer coefficients such that $\cos(nt) =P_n(cos(t))$ for all  $t \in \mathbb{R}$ , one can prove that $\cos(n)$ is irrational for all $n$. Is there an 'easy' way to prove this without relying on **(1)**.

Comment: You can always just prove (1) by using Lindemann's theorem that if $\alpha$ is algebraic, $e^\alpha$ is transcendental. Then using that $i$ is algebraic and $e^{i}=\cos 1+i\sin 1$, you get (1).

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic the proof of the irrationality of $e$ relying on the Taylor series of the cosine function, for which:
$$\cos(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k n^{2k}}{(2k)!}.$$

Comment: Oh, I was not able to mimic the proof but something along the lines of using the taylor series helped me solve it.